# nested form to update has-many parent AND create a *single* child object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many, nested-form-for

I want a form to edit a single new child object and the parent object in one go (in a has many relationship).  If I create a new child in the controller with `@child = @parent.children.new`, the following works, but it displays input fields for *all* existing children.

```
<%= simple_form_for @parent do |p| %>
  <%= p.input :parent_attribute %>
  <%= p.simple_fields_for :children do |c| %>
    <%= c.input :child_attribute %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

How can I display form input fields for only the single new child that was created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to display the new single child form within the parent form, you can do this:

```
<%= simple_form_for @parent do |p| %>
  <%= p.input :parent_attribute %>
  <%= p.simple_fields_for :child, @child do |c| %>
    <%= c.input :child_attribute %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Note that you have to specify both the child model name, as well as the child model object to `simple_fields_for` (or `fields_for`) to reference a specific model object.

If you only want to display the new single child form, you can do this:

```
<%= m.simple_form_for @child do |c| %>
  <%= c.input :child_attribute %>
<% end %>
```

This will create the form only for the new child record.

Comment: I accidentally had m.simple_fields_for in my original code. it should be p.simple_fields_for and p.simple_form_for. I fixed in mine but it won't let me fix in your copy/paste. maybe edit that when you have a sec.

Comment: @TimKoelkebeck I just fixed that.  I hadn't noticed it when I copied it from your original.  Glad that it's all working for you.  Enjoy!